# How to update statistics cookies on file save?

Tags: org-mode, hooks, todo

For some reason, I can't get either of these to work. I'm trying to update the statistics cookies on TODO's automatically when the file saves.

```
(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'org-update-statistics-cookies)
```

```
(add-hook 'after-save-hook (lambda () (org-update-statistics-cookies (current-buffer))))
```

Both give me the following error:

```
run-hooks: Wrong number of arguments: #<subr org-update-statistics-cookies>, 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `org-update-statistics-cookies` with the current buffer as argument is misleading but it would probably work anyway (because it would not be `nil`).

But if you added *both* functions to the hook, that would explain why you get the error: the first (wrong) addition to the hook is run even after you add the second (more-or-less correct) function to it. Both functions get to run, the second one really doing the job of updating the cookies, the first one failing with the indicated error.

Check the hook with `C-h v after-save-hook` and if you find the first addition there, clean it up:

```el
(remove-hook 'after-save-hook #'org-update-statistics-cookies)
```

And clean up the second to just use `t`, not the value that `current-buffer` returns (which is irrelevant and misleading here):

```el
(add-hook 'after-save-hook (lambda () (org-update-statistics-cookies t)))
```

See the doc string of the function with `C-h v org-update-statistics-cookies`.

---

EDIT: Actually, I'm not sure `after-save-hook` is the correct hook to use: it is run after the buffer is saved to its file, but the hook would then modify the buffer. But it's likely that `before-save-hook` is a better choice: the hook is run just before the buffer is saved, so any modifications to the buffer by the hook will also be saved.

I haven't tested however so take all this with a grain of salt.

Comment: Thank you, after-save-hook worked just fine.